# Validation is not work on laravel 5.2.32

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2.32, the validation of it is not work. I have tried to find solution on google and stackoverflow. However, the solution which can fix the 5.2.20 to 5.2.26 cannot fix the problem of laravel 5.2.32. Who can help me?

I have changed the router in the web middleware, the code as the following:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('app/welcome');
    });

    Route::post('/signup', 'UserController@postSignup');
    Route::post('/signin', 'UserController@postSignin');
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'UserController@getDashboard');
    Route::get('/logout', 'UserController@getLogout');
});
```

I also change the Kernel.php as the following. But it's still not work.

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \app\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \app\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ];
```

The code in my controller as below:

```
namespace app\Http\Controllers;

use app\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use app\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\View\Middleware\ErrorBinder;
use Validator;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    // public function __construct()
    // {
    //     $this->middleware('auth');
    // }

    public function postSignUp(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required | email | unique:users',
        'first_name' => 'required | max:60',
        'password' => 'required | min:8'
        ]);

        if ($request['password'] === $request['password_confirmation'])
        {
            $user = new User();

            $user->first_name = $request['first_name'];
            $user->email = $request['email'];
            $user->password = bcrypt($request['password']);

            $user->save();

            Auth::login($user);

            return view('app/dashboard');
        }

        // return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried the validation on laravel 5.2.31, it's works. I don't know why, and I try to find the problem in the original code on 5.2.32, but I fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need the middleware `web` in your route anymore as its baked in to the latest version, s can do without the following:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {...
```

and your kernel something like...

```
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    ];
```